# Python set dict key's value by modifying it's reference

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I wonder how to accomplish something like this in python:

```
d = {'a': 3}
a_value_ref = d['a']
a_value_ref = 6
assert d['a'] == 6
```

I want to first calculate reference to a specific value in a multilevel dict and then modify it by using this mechanism. Is it possible? It's easy using C/C++. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just because something is easy in one language doesn't mean it's an appropriate idiom in another.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a better understanding of how Python variables work.

Comment: Perhaps you could build a new class of mutable `int`s, not that i would recommend it... What's the bigger picture here? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, because integers assignment changes its reference, and you cannot change its value without that (immutability of integers)

You could do that using a single integer in a list, that would work.

```
d = {'a': [3]}
a_value_ref = d['a']
a_value_ref[0] = 6
assert d['a'] == [6]
```

Comment: A workaround is a technique for getting working code in the presence of a bug. This is just an unnecessary modification to the data structure to accommodate a non-Pythonic idiom.

Comment: I'd call it a bad idea.

Comment: I don't propose anything (beyond reading the link I posted in the comments), because I this is an XY problem and I don't know what the OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: @chepner you've got a point :) however, 4 upvotes for that question, so it seems to interest some people.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a way how Python works, workarounds are not a good solutions. I have changed the way of accessing dict's keys and now I update values using the `dict[key] = value` syntax.